# Intermittent error on fb apps when viewed on mobile devices

Tags: facebook

Since mid-February, there have been occasions where our apps throw the error 'The mobile version of the app is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access.'

The issue is - all our applications *are* configured for mobile access. They worked fine last year, and continue to work *most* of the time, but occasionally throw an error that we can't pinpoint. We haven't made any changes in our software in the past month.

Are others experiencing this?

I know FB pushed new migrations in early February, is this related?

Apps that have had this issue:

```
http://m.odylfarm.com/eleanorandpark/
http://m.odylfarm.com/lauracardinal/
```

We have tried changing the URL to https:// - but this does not have an affect.